# How to plot a function with plot() in R with a step size of 0.5?

Tags: r

New to R. I'm given a function f(x)=x^3-3x+7. I need to plot this function in red and plot its derivative with a step-size of 0.5 in blue. dfx vs x in the same graph. I have plotted f(x), but i cant plot dfx with adjusted step size.
My code:

```
f1 <- function(x) {x^3-3*x+7}
exp = D(expression(x^3-3*x+7),'x')
f2 <- function(x) {D(exp,'x')}
curve(f1,from=-2,to=2,col='red')
curve(exp,col='blue',add=TRUE,type='p')
```

I need the points to be plotted at an interval of 0.5 and also draw a line to connect them

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you need. If by changing the step size you mean that **both** curves be entirely visible in the same plot, that can be done by increasing the limits on the y-axis:

```
curve(f1, from = -2, to = 2, col='red', add = F, ylim = c(0,10))
curve(exp, col = 'blue', add = T, type = 'p')
```

[image]